# Kendo UI Grid -- Sort date as string

Tags: html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo UI, and I am looking to default sort date, but can't figure out how to modify this. In this moment kendo sort date as string and i need sort date correctly.
when do i can the sort date?

Comment: A little more context would be helpful. Make sure you are setting the field type to "date" in your datasource schema.model

Comment: Please provide the codes to examine.

Answer (score 1):

In your model you need to declare which one is a date, eg.

```
model: {
       id: "Id",
       fields: {
               Id: {},
               Date: { type: "date" },
               Day: {},
               Shift: {}                        
               }
       }
```

And when you declare column it should be something like this;

```
columns:
    [
        { field: "Date", format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" },
        { field: "Day" },
        { field: "Shift" }
    ]
```

Hope this helps.